# Por que ocorre este erro de name 'sys' is not defined?

Tags: python-3.x

Por que ocorre este erro de `name 'sys' is not defined`?

```
while True :
    print ('Digite exit para sair')
    response = input ()
    if response == 'exit':
        sys.exit()
        print('Você digitou' + response + ',')

/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files/bin/qpython3-android5.sh "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/exSair.py" && exit
e/emulated/0/qpython/exSair.py" && exit  <
Digite exit para sair
exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/exSair.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit()
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
1|u0_a266@jflte:/ $
```

Comment: Não é mais fácil testar o caso que `response` não é igual a `'exit'` e deixar sem `sys.exit()`?

Comment: E deve ter faltado o `import sys` no começo do programa

Comment: E aprenda a formatar sua pergunta no SOpt.

Comment: Vlw. Obrigado,  estou aprendendo e sou novo no stack.

Comment: Fala @IsmaeldosSantosCardoso! Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt). Dá uma olhada nesse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O módulo `sys` não está definido em tempo de execução pois não foi importado.

No topo do seu código, adicione:

```
import sys
```

[Documentação de `import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).